# Could we inherit the stackoverflow "dark mode" here on GIS.SE?

Tags: feature-request, design

Just a thought; I'm wondering if it could be possible for -- night owls -- to somehow "inherit" the newly developed "[dark mode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/)" on Stackoverflow also on sub-sites, in particular on our, here on GIS.SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that we can do from GIS SE.  It would need to come from the SE developers.

This has been discussed at [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites) where [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345762/215590) from @Glorfindel said on 30 Mar 2020:

> Currently, Dark Mode is available as a beta test on Stack Overflow
>   only. More details can be found in [this Meta Stack Overflow
>   question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits).
>   At the moment, it isn't clear if and how/when it will be rolled out to
>   other sites in the network:
>
> > #### Future releases
> >
> > At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the
> >     network two years ago makes updating our LESS easier, creating dark
> >     versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones,
> >     is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this
> >     time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark
> >     because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be
> >     honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.

Other answers to that question mention extensions you can use with your browser as a workaround to achieve a level of dark mode.

Comment: Ok, wait and see so...

Comment: There are browser extensions that do this, you can choose which sites you want to be in dark mode.